# Overwriting previously installed .NET winforms app

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Sorry if this has been asked before, I've searched but cannot find an answer.  I've created a WinForms VB.NET app and deployed to it a server using the Visual Studio publish tool. On the server it installed to this directory automatically:

> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local
>   Settings\Apps\2.0\C8TQL85O.NPG\WDKBJDPD.HQO\expi..tion_550653a49cafdf54_0001.0000_dd22cceef4d5bb47\MyReport.exe"

Today I made some changes to the app, and deployed it again.  On the server when I installed it, it automatically installed in this directory:

> "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local
>   Settings\Apps\2.0\C8TQL85O.NPG\WDKBJDPD.HQO\expi..tion_550653a49ca0b3f4_0001.0000_dd22cceea4d5cc47\MyReport.exe"

I missed it at first, but the second directory is *slightly* different to the first.
Have I inadvertently installed a duplicate app now, so both versions are installed?

If so, how do I get the app installation routine to overwrite the previous version?

Also, I use Windows Task Scheduler to launch the .EXE, which means I need to keep updating this to match the directory.  Is it possible to install into a specific directory that remains the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wishing for your app to get updates? Such as, you install it the first time, and when you republish, it downloads the new version?

Comment: Yes I suppose that would be okay.  Can you offer me any pointers as to how this is done please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're publishing to a network drive, where this app will be installed from, it's actually not that hard.

- Use the publish wizard: Build Menu -> Publish "Project Name Here"
- Select the network drive path where the application's files will be
  published to
- On the following menu, select "From a UNC Path or File Share, and chose the same path as the prior screen.
- Next, depending on your project's use, you will select the applications offline preferences. I usually go with Yes. Click next, then finish.

When users install the app from the UNC path, they will get an icon in their start menu (if you chose yes on offline prefs) and they can run it from there. The exe itself will live in a folder much like the one's in your question that you can target  with Windows scheduler, but you're going to have to go find it.

Comment: Thanks.  The development machine and live (web) server however are not connected via network.  I can access the web server directory via FTP, so should be able to publish to FTP in the Publish Wizard to get around this.  In the next step, "How will users install this application" in the UNC path field do I enter the server's directory, because at this point this path won't be accessible from the development machine?  Thanks.

Comment: You would want to specify from a website (the 'http: //webserver/AppFolder/' for your application) so that you can then link to the install package on your web server, have people install it, and have it check for updates at that location.

Comment: I spent a lot of time experimenting with this yesterday.  Even when an update path is specified, .NET installs the application in a new directory, so that it can roll back a version if required.

Comment: To completely replace the existing application you have to use InstallWise LE packaged with VS2012 instead of the ClickOnce deployment method (although for some reason I don't have it in my VS).  According to other developers presents a new load of problems, not least of which it is apparently upgrade-ware.  So in actual fact it would be a lot of work just to save me updating my Schedule Task program location.  Anyway I've learned a lot from your post, so thank you for helping me out. :-)